# Changing class based on data from API

Tags: javascript

I updated this with the current answer and it still doesnt change the class on the UVIndex

function showUvIndex(data){

```
let UVInumber = Math.round(data.current.uvi);

uvIndex.classList = "btn btn-lg";

if (UVInumber == 11) {
    uvIndex.classList.add('extreme');
  } else if ([8, 9, 10].includes(UVInumber)) {
    uvIndex.classList.add('very-high');
  } else if ([6, 7].includes(UVInumber)) {
    uvIndex.classList.add('high');
  } else if ([3, 4, 5].includes(UVInumber)) {
    uvIndex.classList.add('moderate');
  } else if ([0, 1, 2].includes(UVInumber)) {
    uvIndex.classList.add('low');
  };

console.log(UVInumber);
```

};

Comment: Provide more details, please, if there is any errors in console, or anything, we cant guess, sorry.
Or you can use the Debugger functionality, it should be your friend #1 actually. Put a breakpoint or put `debugger;` somewhere where you need and go step-by-step execution.

Comment: `uvIndex.classList = "btn btn-lg";` is wrong, use `classList.add` like in your other statements, or assign [`uvIndex.className = "btn btn-lg";`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className).

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect syntax in your if statements, you cannot compare your UVInumber with set of values in that way.

Here is a valid example

```
if (UVInumber == 11) {
  uvIndex.classList.add('extreme');
} else if ([8, 9, 10].includes(UVInumber)) {
  uvIndex.classList.add('very-high');
} else if ([6, 7].includes(UVInumber)) {
  uvIndex.classList.add('high');
} else if ([3, 4, 5].includes(UVInumber)) {
  uvIndex.classList.add('moderate');
} else if ([1, 2].includes(UVInumber)) {
  uvIndex.classList.add('low');
}
```

And here is a more read-friendly example

```
const UVInumber = 10;

const classMap = [{
    class: "extreme",
    values: [11]
  },
  {
    class: "very-high",
    values: [8, 9, 10]
  },
  {
    class: "high",
    values: [6, 7]
  },
  {
    class: "moderate",
    values: [3, 4, 5]
  },
  {
    class: "low",
    values: [1, 2]
  }
];

const classToAdd = classMap.find(x => x.values.includes(UVInumber)).class;

console.log(classToAdd)
```

Comment: what about if i wanted to add else if UVInumber is greater than 8 but less then 11 add UV class very high?

Comment: Depends, you can change the first object in the list i provided with values: [11,10,9], in case you want to map that range to "extreme",
Or you can replace values with 2 additional fields, like `min` and `max` and `.find(x => x.max < UVInumber && x.min >= UVInumbere`.
Everything depends on your requirements and imagination.
But the root issue you had - syntax in if statements
You had to write `if (UVINumber == 8 || UVINumber == 9 || UVINumber == 10)` and so on